# High CPU usage when typing in TexMaker. Is this normal?

Tags: texmaker

Background: I am a beginner at LaTex. I didn't know how to install LaTex and packages properly. I remember installing the Tikz/PGF package, but I don't know how. Then after assuming that everything was good to go, I proceeded to learn to write in LaTex for a few days. However, when I write my LaTex document, my CPU usage ramps up to 100%. Is this expected?

[image: 100% CPU Usage after writing my LaTex Document]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Depends on your used system. More informations are needed ...

Comment: It looks like you have 6 or more compilations (pdfTeX) running concurrently, which would be weird.  Manually installing TikZ/PGF is also weird, since that should have come with the default packages.  Are you using MikTeX or TeXLive?  What editor are you using to edit the .tex files (perhaps texmaker, given the tag)?  How are you compiling the .tex files to get the .pdf files?

Comment: @Teepeemm, I am using MikTex as what the front page of the LaTex website had initially recommended. For the manual installation of TikZ/PGF, I didn't know that it already came with the default package until now. Also, yes, I used TexMaker. And, maybe? I don't know how this works. I press the quick build, then View PDF whenever I make changes.